# How can I calculate a future date based on a form entry using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

Using JavaScript, I need to calculate a date in the future (two years minus one day) based on the date a user enters into a form. Any suggestions?

Comment: What format has the date entered in the form?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a library for this such as [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any libraries using the `Date` object:

```
var d = new Date(inputValue);
d.setYear(d.getFullYear() + 2);
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
alert(d.toString()); // Thu Jan 28 2016 <timestamp/timezone>
```

The `inputValue` would be the date entered, but it would need to be [an accepted format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Examples), such as MM-DD-YYYY.

You will need `d.getFullYear` on the second line, since .getYear would return 114 right now (years since 1900).

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)! It's a great library for formatting and manipulating dates.